# Bash script to send all Wifi hotspot traffic over separate VPN tunnel on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, bash, openvpn, wlan

I'm working on a bash script that is supposed to create a hotspot on ubuntu 18. However I have special needs about what connection that hotspot is supposed to use.

I want all and any traffic from devices connected to my hotspot to go over a separate VPN tunnel and (not sure this part is relevant) I will randomize which VPN gets chosen from a set of options each time I activate the hotspot.

By default, when creating a hotspot on Ubuntu 18, it will simply share the existing connection whatever it currently happens to be.

When I open `nm-connection-editor` the GUI contains a VPN option, but I don't know how to create and modify a Hotspot by purely using bash.

I'm basically stuck not knowing how to make it happen programatically or if I lack some other knowledge to achieve this. Unless I missed something there, man pages for `nmcli` haven't been helpful to me.

What probably complicates things is that I'm already connected to a VPN on tun0, so I'm guessing I need to create a separate VPN connection, let's say over tun1 and make the hotspot use it.

Here is what I have so far

```
#that's the kind of call I use to activate my main VPN connection
#you can assume I have script already that gives me 
#the value for mainconnectionuuid
nmcli con up uuid mainconnectionuuid #activates tun0, all traffic goes through tun0 after this

#now I want to activate a hotspot that uses a different VPN connection 
#the following code activates the hotspot, but there is no option
#to separate the traffic to go over a different VPN
nmcli radio wifi on
nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid somessid password somepassword
```

What I need is something like this:

```
#activate main connection on tun0
nmcli con up uuid mainconnectionuuid

nmcli radio wifi on
#'useconnection' is a phantasy parameter here, but I need something like this
#assuming here that the connection under vpnforhotspotuuid would already define tun1 to be used
nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid somessid password somepassword **useconnection vpnforhotspotuuid**
```

Or like this:

```
#activate main connection on tun0
nmcli con up uuid mainconnectionuuid

#activate connection for hotspot on tun1
nmcli con up uuid vpnforhotspotuuid

nmcli radio wifi on
#'usetunnel' is a phantasy parameter here
nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid somessid password somepassword **usetunnel tun1**
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm not a major expert, I can write bash scripts and I know ufw but I'm somewhat scared of IPtables. I would appreciate a solution that is not too hard to understand as I also want to be able to write a script that undoes or at least deactivates the changes.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried the proposed solution by Piotr and it seems to almost work, but something goes wrong. When I connect to that hotspot with an android 9 device it seems to work until I execute the last command `ip route add default via $TUN1IP table hotspot`. After issuing that, I just have just enough time to request whatismyip.com with a browser on the phone and verify that I indeed have the tun1 ip. Short time later (maybe about 15-30 s), the phone wifi settings will start saying "no internet connection" and the phone starts reconnecting in an endless loop until I undo the routing with `ip route del default table hotspot`

Frist I wondered if this was some kind of firewall issue as my configuration is very strict and starts with

```
ufw default deny incoming 
ufw default deny outgoing
```

and then I have some rules to allow vpn connections and local addresses, then regarding the hotspot so far I settled on:

```
ufw allow out on tun1 to 0.0.0.0/0
ufw allow out on wlan0 to 10.57.213.1/24
```

**Edit 2**

Before issuing the final command `ip route add default via $TUN1IP table hotspot` I see following UFW block (via `dmesg`), but the connection works anyways though:

> [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=10.57.213.181
>   DST=10.57.213.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=xxxxx DF PROTO=UDP
>   SPT=45104 DPT=4886 LEN=8

Those blocks disappear after issuing the routing command, so I'm guessing they are not significant, not sure though. However if I look at non-ufw messages I see following messages on each reconnection:

> netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length.

I googled a little and some people [say](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1570903) it's a bug related to WPA2 and that the connection will work if I disable encryption, but even if I disable encryption nothing changes. The device is still reconnecting to the hotspot in an endless loop.

I should probably also mention that I tried `ip route flush cache` but it changes nothing

**Edit 3**

`wpa_cli -i wlan0 log_level DEBUG` and subsequent `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -e` yields (I censored PID and MAC adresses using letter x):

> ```
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-70 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xd740 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-72 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xd750 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:22 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:33 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:33 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=20:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-75 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0x8830 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:33 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:33 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-72 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe430 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-70 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe450 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-71 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe470 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-71 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe480 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-71 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe490 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlan0
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: nl80211: RX frame da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff sa=10:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx bssid=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff freq=2412 ssi_signal=-71 fc=0x40 seq_ctrl=0xe4a0 stype=4
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (19) received
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: P2P: Not a P2P probe - ignore it
> Mar 05 20:59:41 machineone wpa_supplicant[xxxx]: Ignore Probe Request due to DS Params mismatch: chan=1 != ds.chan=2
> ```

**Edit 4**

After activation of tun1 my routing table looks like this

```
Destination       Gateway           Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0           10.10.2.1         0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0           10.10.3.1         0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0           192.168.xxx.xxx   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.10.2.0         0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
10.10.3.0         0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun1
10.57.213.1       0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0 
the.vpn.ip.tun0   192.168.xxx.xxx   255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0       0.0.0.0           255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0 
the.vpn.ip.tun1   192.168.xxx.xxx   255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.yyy.0     0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.xxx.0     0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.xxx.xxx   0.0.0.0           255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

I experimented with commands such as `ip route add default dev wlan0 via default dev tun1` and `ip route add default dev wlp8s0 via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1` but nothing worked. Additionally, sometimes the default gateway for tun0 happens to be the same as for tun1.

**edit 5**

I discovered there is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1570903) in the linux kernel (or rather `wpa2_supplicant`) where the kernel is extremely strict with arguments passed to it and makes `wpa2_supplicant` fail. I did the following

```
# nmcli connection edit hotspot
set 802-11-wireless-security.pmf disable
save
[CTRL+D]
```

This disables Protected Management Frames (PMF) for the hotspot connection I created which is where the kernel call happens that breaks `wpa_supplicant`. After having done this (and `route add default dev wlan0 via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1`) now my whole system (not just the hotspot) is running over `tun1` instead of `tun0`. I still need to understand why I can't make it happen that `tun0` would be used for `eth0` while at the same time `tun1` would be used for `wlan0`.

After I issue the following commands

```
ip route add default dev wlan0 via 10.10.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50
ip route add default dev eth0 via 10.10.3.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50
```

My routing table looks like this:

```
0.0.0.0          10.10.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0          10.10.3.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0          192.168.xxx.xxx  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.10.2.0        0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
10.10.3.0        0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun1
10.55.213.1      0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
the.vpn.ip.tun1  192.168.xxx.xxx  255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0      0.0.0.0          255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
the.vpn.ip.tun1  192.168.xxx.xxx  255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.yyy.0    0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.xxx.0    0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.xxx.xxx  0.0.0.0          255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

which looks the same as if I never issued them

**edit 6:**

when I try to make the vpn connection from the terminal

```
sudo openvpn --config myconfigfile.ovpn --dev tun1 --verb 3
```

following route commands get issued and everything will go through `tun1` and `tun0` is ignored:

```
Wed Mar 11 19:16:12 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Wed Mar 11 19:16:12 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 10.10.2.6/24 broadcast 10.10.2.255
Wed Mar 11 19:16:12 2020 /sbin/ip route add the.vpn.ip.tun1/32 via 10.10.3.1
Wed Mar 11 19:16:12 2020 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.1
Wed Mar 11 19:16:12 2020 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.1
```

I also find the `10.10.3.1` ip odd since it's related to `tun0`.

When I do

```
ip route delete 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.1
```

all my connections return to `tun0` and ignore `tun1`. `ip route show table` looks like this:

```
default via 10.10.3.1 dev tun0 
default via 10.10.3.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.xxx.xxx dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.10.2.0/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.2.3 
10.10.3.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.4 metric 50 
10.55.213.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.55.213.1 metric 600 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.1 dev tun1 
the.tun0.vpn.ip via 192.168.xxx.xxx dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
the.tun1.vpn.ip via 10.10.3.1 dev tun0 
192.168.aaa.bbb/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.aaa.ccc linkdown 
192.168.xxx.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.xxx.yyy metric 100 
192.168.xxx.xxx dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100 
broadcast 10.10.2.0 dev tun1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.2.3 
local 10.10.2.3 dev tun1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.10.2.3 
broadcast 10.10.2.255 dev tun1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.2.3 
broadcast 10.10.3.0 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.4 
local 10.10.3.4 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.10.3.4 
broadcast 10.10.3.255 dev tun0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.4 
broadcast 10.55.213.0 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.55.213.1 
local 10.55.213.1 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.55.213.1 
broadcast 10.55.213.255 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.55.213.1 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.aaa.bbb dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.aaa.ccc linkdown 
local 192.168.aaa.ccc dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.aaa.ccc 
broadcast 192.168.aaa.255 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.aaa.ccc linkdown 
broadcast 192.168.xxx.0 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.xxx.yyy 
local 192.168.xxx.yyy dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.xxx.yyy 
broadcast 192.168.xxx.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.xxx.yyy
```

I hope I edited all those ip's correctly as in reality some ip's change each time, so I'm matching them with my previous edits.

My poor intuition told me to try next

```
ip route replace 10.57.213.1/24 via 10.10.2.6 dev tun1 table AirSpot
```

But all I get is `Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.` and I don't understand what it means. I'm just not getting something. Routing is not exactly intuitive to me. With that line I want that any packets addressed from or to `10.57.213.1/24` (which is the manually set hotspot range) are to go through `10.10.2.6`, which I would think (based on the verbose output of `openvpn`) is where the `tun1` is.

Edit 7:

I think this is some kind of default route issue, but I'm not expert enough to solve it..

Comment: What you are looking for is called [policy routing](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I can manage with that information and that little explanation alone. Let's say my vpn tunnel `tun1` for hotspot runs on `10.0.0.10`. Would it be `echo 200 Hotspot >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` , `ip rule add from 10.0.0.10 table Hotspot` , `ip route add default [?] via dev tun1 table Hotspot` and then `ip route flush cache` to activate? I also don't know what IP adress to enter where the question mark is. I'm cable connected via `eth0`, router ip range 192.168.x.x. `tun1` will run over eth0. Or is this supposed to be some kind of ip that is assigned to the hotspot?

Comment: The netlink _"error"_ is just a warning to help fix broken software, while the firewall hit is Firefox Mobile _"wifi-tickle"_, which is used to keep Androids WiFi up. Your Android device has connections problems. Enable debug logging on the `wpa_supplicant` (`wpa_cli -i wlan0 log_level DEBUG`) and add some logs to the question (`journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -e`).

Comment: Another idea I had, maybe `nmcli` screws something up. Couldn't I just use `openvpn` command directly by passing the *.ovpn file to it? Would that make any difference? I'm enabling the tun1 connection using `nmcli` right now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you posted in a comment is almost correct. What is missing is the correct IP addresses to use.

#### Step 1: Retrieve information

You need to retrieve two pieces of information:

1. The IP addresses of the subnetwork of your hotspot. By default these are a random network of the form `10.42.*.0/24`, so you need to fix the addresses. The easiest way is to create a new WiFi connection called `hotspot` using `nm-connection-editor`. You need to:

   - set the mode to `Hotspot` in the *"Wi-Fi"* tab,
   - set the method to `Shared with other computers` in the *"IPv4 Settings"* tab,
   - choose an subnet for the network by adding on IP address (e.g. `10.57.213.1` with netmask `24`) in the same tab,
   - add some authentication method (e.g. a PSK)

   After performing these steps, you should have a well configured `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/hotspot.nmconnection` file with a content like:

   ```
   [wifi]
   mode=ap

   [ipv4]
   address1=10.57.213.1/24
   method=shared
   ```

   and you can start the connection with `nmcli connection up id hotspot`.
2. The IP address of the VPN gateway. Whether this is fixed or variable depends on what kind of VPN you are using. Let's say it's `10.10.10.1`.

#### Step 2: Configure policy routing

1. A one-time operation. We need an additional routing table. In order to be able to refer to it by name let's add:

   ```
   200 hotspot
   ```

   to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.
2. Once per system boot. We need to tell  the kernel, that packets originating from `10.57.213.0/24` should use the `hotspot` table:

   ```
   ip rule add from 10.57.213.0/24 table hotspot
   ```
3. Every time we connect to a VPN, we need to add a default route for the HotSpot addresses:

   ```
   ip route replace default via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1 table hotspot
   ```

   where `10.10.3.1` is the address of the other side of your VPN tunnel according to the routing table.

   You can run this part in a [NetworkManager dispatcher script](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html), in which case the gateway address will be in the environment variable `$IP4_GATEWAY`.

**Edit:** To automatically establish the default route for the `hotspot` table add a dispatcher script `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/hotspot.sh` like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Be verbose until you test this
set -ex

# First parameter passed by NM: interface
DEVICE="$1"
# Second parameter: action
CMD="$2"
IP=/bin/ip

# Delete the part after '/' from $IP4_ADDRESS_0
LOCAL_IP=${IP4_ADDRESS_0%/*}
if [ "$LOCAL_IP" != "" ]; then
  # Add a 'src' option to the route only if the IP is not empty
  SRC="src $LOCAL_IP"
fi

if [ "$CMD" = "vpn-up" ]; then
  $IP route replace default via $IP4_GATEWAY dev $DEVICE $SRC table hotspot
fi
```

I didn't test this.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to almost work, but something goes wrong. When I connect to that hotspot with an android 9 device it seems to work until I execute the last command `ip route add default via $TUN1IP table hotspot`. After issuing that, I just have just enough time to request whatismyip.com with a browser on the phone and verify that I have the `tun1` ip. Shortly after that (about 30 s maybe), the phone wifi settings will start saying "no connection" and the phone starts reconnecting in an endless loop until i undo the routing with `ip route del default table hotspot`

Comment: What are you using as `$TUN1IP`? It should be the (private) IP address of the remote peer (`ip addr` shows it as `peer`), not the IP address of the `tun1` interface.

Comment: oh, i see... I use the local tun1 address `10.x.x.x` of the `tun1` interface with this very (very) ugly expression: `TUN1IP=$(ifconfig | grep -A 2 "tun1" | grep inet | grep -o -E -e "inet(\s)*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"| grep -o -E -e "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")` Do you mean I should use the external vpn ip address that `tun1` connects to and not its `10.x.x.x` address? I'll try that and come back here..

Comment: You should probably forget the deprecated `ifconfig` and use [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) instead. Also, if you use a **NetworkManager** script as in the edited question, you have the local and gateway IP addresses served on a plate (in the `IP4_ADDRESS_0` and `IP4_GATEWAY` variables).

Comment: `ip route add default via $REMOTEVPNIP table hotspot` where `$REMOTEVPNIP` is just a string with manually set IP address of the remote VPN server that `tun1` connects to yields `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.` When defining the connection using `nm-connection-editor` I didn't set any gateway. Is that maybe an issue? Is that where I'm supposed to enter the `10.x.x.x` `tun1` address? Is that that what `IP4_GATEWAY` is supposed to be? I didn't want to use the dispatcher script right away as I felt, it requires additional study how to use it.

Comment: You need to use the private address of the VPN server. Basically `ip addr dev tun1` will give you a line `inet 10.210.77.17 peer 10.210.77.1/32 scope global tun1`: `10.210.77.17` is the address on your `tun1` interface, while `10.210.77.1` is the address of the other side of the tunnel. You need to use the latter.

Comment: In the output of `ip address` the word `peer` is nowhere to be seen. instead it says `brd` under tun1: `inet 10.x.x.x/xx brd 10.x.x.y scope global noprefixroute tun1` I'll try the brd address just in case..

Comment: `brd` is the broadcast address. You don't mention what kind of VPN you are using, so it's hard to guess how routing is configured, but the VPN software certainly configures some route: check `ip route` and look for `via 10.x.x.z`.

Comment: the via address for tun1 is the same as for tun0. Is that normal? `default via 10.x.x.a dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 10.x.x.a dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
10.x.x.b/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.x.x.c metric 50 
10.x.x.b/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.x.x.d metric 50` About the provider: Is it possible to send private messages here? Generally I use openvpn with *.ovpn files. The provider offers a client as well but I don't want to use it.

Comment: No, it isn't, but people lack imagination and out of 65536 possible values for `x.x` they always choose `0.0` or similar. If you use your VPN only to access the Internet, you shouldn't have too many problems.

Comment: Well, I don't want to disclose unnecessary details so the whole internet would know my security setup ;) I tried `ip route add default via 10.x.x.x table hotspot` with all possible ip's (doing `ip route del ..` between) that I could come up with and none of them worked. It seems the default is always the first vpn connection activated via `nmcli` and it is somehow forced for the hotspot. I wonder if I need to change other settings of the `tun1` connection. Basically I just edited it by replacing `tun` with `tun1` in advanced settings. Maybe I need make manual IPv4 settings for `tun1`?

Comment: Routing your packets through half the world so that they enter the Internet from another IP address is not security. Besides the addresses in the `10.0.0.0/8` network are private addresses, they are not unique and disclosing them has no impact. You should [learn more about Linux networking](https://opensource.com/business/16/8/introduction-linux-network-routing) to understand why two default routes are a bad idea.

Comment: I read the article, but I may need to read more. I think I got a rough idea already, but I still don't understand enough to solve it. I added my routing table to my question now. I thought that `ip route add default dev wlan0 via default dev tun1` would work, but it didn't. The routing table is form before I issued that command.

Comment: Yes, you should read other articles about basic networking. From what you posted, `10.10.3.1` is the gateway at the other end of the VPN tunnel (so `via 10.10.3.1`). Besides that `192.168.0.0/16` is another range of addresses for private use, masking them is not necessary (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

Comment: when I issue `ip route add default dev wlp8s0 via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1` all my 'tun1' and `tun0` traffic completely stops. `dmesg` shows `ufw` only blocks connections from `192.168.xxx.xxx` to `224.0.0.1` and from `192.168.xxx.xxx` to `192.168.xxx.yyy` which as far I understand it, should be irrelevant.
I'm more concerned about `netlink: 'wpa_supplicant': attribute type 213 has an invalid length`. Those only appear when I do  the `ip route add ...` command. I still don't understand where this is coming from. When doing `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -e` should I look for smething specific there?

Comment: I solved the problem where my traffic stopped, it was an issue with `wpa_supplicant` and kernel, however I still can't get the correct interface to use the correct tunnel (see my edit)

Comment: The key element of the solution is to use another routing table (called `hotspot`) for traffic coming from the AP. You need to issue `ip route replace default via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1 table hotspot`. As far as I remember `ifconfig` only shows the `main` table (it is considered deprecated anyway), so check with `ip route show table hotspot` or `ip route show table all`.

Comment: I included the output of `ip route show table all` after starting `tun1` via openvpn in terminal and just after `ip route delete 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.1`. I'm assuming it's at that state where I have to issue the elusive routing command that is supposed to make my hotspot traffic go through `tun1` while everything else goes through `tun0`. I wouldn't have thought that something so simple could be so complicated to do :(

Comment: You don't need to touch your **main** routing table, just that called `AirSpot` in your question. Since your table is empty (`ip route show table AirSpot` gives you an empty output) you just need to add a default route `ip route add default via 10.10.3.1 dev tun1 table AirSpot` and check that the `ip rule` you added is still there `ip rule`.